# How to redirect ex command output into current buffer or file?

Tags: vim, command, redirect, buffer

How can I redirect or pipe the output of an ex command into my current buffer or a file?

For example, I want to read the contents of all the registers into the current buffer, which in ex mode is shown using `:registers`.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13881/10254 might be of interest, basically **get input, then run command, capture and put**. With vimscript functions, `Capture(excmd)` `PutAfterCapture(command)` `GetInputCommandThenCaptureAndPut()`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
:redir >name_of_registers_file
:registers
:redir END
:r name_of_registers_file
:help redir
```

The last command is very useful, since there are lots of options for redirection: to variables, to registers, how to append, further cornucopia.

I still find it weird and annoying that it uses END that way, but since everything else that can follow `redir` has to start with a non-word-character, at least it's not ambiguous.

**PS** AFAIK (which is pretty far in this case) there's no way to read it directly into the buffer: you have to store it in a register or a variable first.  Check the help for the various options of how to do that.

**PPS** If you do want to do this using a variable —maybe to encapsulate it in a function and avoid clobbering registers or global variables— you'll have to convert the multiline string that gets written to the variable into a list.  EG

```
:call append( '.', split(variable_you_redirected_to, "\n") )
```

Otherwise (if you just do `append('.',var)`) you end up with ^@'s (nulls) instead of newlines, since that's what vimscript uses to represent newlines in String variables.

*edit*: as @Bill Odom mentions, using `:put =variable_you_redirected_to` is a lot easier than the complicated `append()` expression.  Thanks, Bill!

---

#### PPPS

I've written a [snippet](http://gist.github.com/362802) to make this stuff more convenient.  It declares a function `Redir(command, target)` and a command `R`.

The command parses the last series of non-space characters as a redirection target and passes that to the function, which does the boilerplate to redirect the command output to the redirection target.

The command is everything after `R` and before the last space.

EG

```
" Store the vim buffer list in buffer_list.txt
:R ls >buffer_list.txt
" Store error messages emitted by a function being debugged
"   in the 'unnamed register'
:R call FunctionBeingDebugged() @">
```

There are a few limitations with this: for example you won't be able to write to a filename that contains a space.  The upside to this is that you don't have to quote your command.  I've got it posted on gist.github.com, and I'll try to keep it updated if I end up improving it.  Or you can fork it yourself</noeuphemism>!

Anyway the snippet is available [here](http://gist.github.com/362802).  It can be dropped into a .vimrc file or into a file in ~/.vim/plugins.

Comment: Using @intuited's `Exec` function from [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8296/32647), a mapping like `:inoremap <C-S-C> <C-R>=Exec("")<Left><Left>` maps Ctrl+Shift+C (for *Command*) to make it easier to insert the output of a command like `:ls` at the current point in the buffer.

Answer (score 39):

@intuited is right; the `redir` command is what you want. A one-liner like this will insert the output of :`registers` into the current buffer:

```
redir => m | silent registers | redir END | put=m
```

That's not something you'll want to type very often, however, and it's not exactly amenable to a key map. I found myself doing this fairly often, so I wrote a function and a handful of commands to make it easier. As a bonus, I can now send command output to a new window or new tab as easily as inserting it into the current buffer. Here's the code (with a few command examples at the very end):

```
" redir_messages.vim
"
" Inspired by the TabMessage function/command combo found
" at <http://www.jukie.net/~bart/conf/vimrc>.
"

function! RedirMessages(msgcmd, destcmd)
"
" Captures the output generated by executing a:msgcmd, then places this
" output in the current buffer.
"
" If the a:destcmd parameter is not empty, a:destcmd is executed
" before the output is put into the buffer. This can be used to open a
" new window, new tab, etc., before :put'ing the output into the
" destination buffer.
"
" Examples:
"
"   " Insert the output of :registers into the current buffer.
"   call RedirMessages('registers', '')
"
"   " Output :registers into the buffer of a new window.
"   call RedirMessages('registers', 'new')
"
"   " Output :registers into a new vertically-split window.
"   call RedirMessages('registers', 'vnew')
"
"   " Output :registers to a new tab.
"   call RedirMessages('registers', 'tabnew')
"
" Commands for common cases are defined immediately after the
" function; see below.
"
    " Redirect messages to a variable.
    "
    redir => message

    " Execute the specified Ex command, capturing any messages
    " that it generates into the message variable.
    "
    silent execute a:msgcmd

    " Turn off redirection.
    "
    redir END

    " If a destination-generating command was specified, execute it to
    " open the destination. (This is usually something like :tabnew or
    " :new, but can be any Ex command.)
    "
    " If no command is provided, output will be placed in the current
    " buffer.
    "
    if strlen(a:destcmd) " destcmd is not an empty string
        silent execute a:destcmd
    endif

    " Place the messages in the destination buffer.
    "
    silent put=message

endfunction

" Create commands to make RedirMessages() easier to use interactively.
" Here are some examples of their use:
"
"   :BufMessage registers
"   :WinMessage ls
"   :TabMessage echo "Key mappings for Control+A:" | map <C-A>
"
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command BufMessage call RedirMessages(<q-args>, ''       )
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command WinMessage call RedirMessages(<q-args>, 'new'    )
command! -nargs=+ -complete=command TabMessage call RedirMessages(<q-args>, 'tabnew' )

" end redir_messages.vim
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize you could just `:put =var`.

Comment: nice, i used this to output a txt file of my keymappings for reference, but just switching it to: `redir => m | silent map | redir END | put=m`

Comment: I have absolutely hijacked this into my own vim config.   (With an attribution, of course, so I don't end up thinking I wrote it.)

Thanks!

Comment: Very useful indeed, and just what I was looking for. - Personally I don't want it to keep asking if I want to lose unsaved changes when I close the window or tab again, II'll not be keeping the results, so I added a commented alternate version of "silent execute a:destcmd" to the code above giving that variation

Comment: In love, and SO SO much of my vimminess is eased now.  Snag'd that into my vimfiles too!  (With apt credits of course, just as @JonCarter said.)  

Comment: `redir =>m |silent messages | redir END | put=m` will dump vim errors for troubleshooting - thanks @Bill Odom

Answer (score 29):

```
:redir @a
:registers
:redir END
"ap
```

`:redir @a` **redirects** all messages from here on to a **register** named `a`. You follow this with your command whose output you want to capture (`:registers` in your case). `:redir END` ends the redirection. `"ap` means, `"a` uses the register named `a` and `p` puts the contents of the selected register into the current buffer.

See [**Capture ex command output**](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) at **Vim Tips Wiki** for more information :-)

Comment: This is shorter and more direct than the accepted answer. Unless there's copious output that you want to store in a file as well this is a better solution.

Comment: From the linked Vim Tip if your ex command is actually an external (shell) command you can just `:read !<shell command>` and pipe the output straight into the buffer.

Answer (score 11):

In addition, `:h :redir`:

> ...To get the output of one command the |execute()| function can be used.

e.g.

```
put = execute('scriptnames')
put = execute('filter /vimfiles/ scriptnames')
```

Comment: This is the easiest way IMO. No saving or variable required.

Answer (score 9):

It is not necessary to use a temporary variable as long as you can save the current buffer and are ok with appending the messages to the end of the current file.

From the Vim documentation:

```
:redi[r] >> {file}      Redirect messages to file {file}.  Append if {file}
                        already exists.  {not in Vi}
```

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:redir

So, to append the messages from `:registers` to the bottom of the current file, do this:

```
:write | redir >> % | silent registers | redir END | edit
```

1. `:write` the file so that any changes won't be lost
2. Begin redirecting output to `%`, the name of the current file.
3. Silently run the `:registers` command.
4. `END` redirecting to the file.
5. `:edit` the file to see the new changes.

You can also forcefully truncate the current file and replace it with the output messages:

```
:redir! > % | silent registers | redir END | edit!
```

But that is probably not what you want to do.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately I have no rep, so I cannot add this as a comment to 'Francis Niu'.

The `execute()`   function looks like the easiest way to accomplish this, and it was added in **vim 8** .

Listed in the new/extended features on vim's github.  [version8.txt](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/doc/version8.txt)