# Vim hardcopy of a search pattern

Tags: vim

How is it possible to :hardcopy all the lines - and only those - resulting from a pattern search ?

I tried :

```
:g/pattern/ha
```

but it did not work (3 occurrences gave 3 hardcopies of the entire file...)

Thanks in advance

PS : I should have added that I wish to print the line numbers AND keep the original line numbers (e.g, pattern in lines 3, 7, 8, print 3, 7, 8 and not 1, 2, 3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try deleting those lines which do not match.

```
:v/pattern/d
:ha
```

To capture the output of `:g//nu`, look into the `:redir` command, according to [Capture ex command output](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) on the Vim wiki. They give this example:

```
:redir @a
:g//nu
:redir END
```

and then paste the output into a new buffer, which you can print.

Comment: It works, except that it does not keep the original line numbers (e.g. pattern in line 3, 7, 8) and outputs the pattern with line numbers 1, 2, 3

Comment: I've added a bit about `:redir` (a command with which I was unfamiliar); see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/vim-how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file