# How do I capture the output of a vim command in a register, without the newlines?

Tags: vim

This is related to this question:
[How to redirect ex command output into current buffer or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/vim-how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file)

However, the problem with using `:redir` is that it causes 3 or 4 extra newlines in front of the output, and they appear to be difficult to remove using the substitute function.

For example, if I do the following:

```
:redir @a  
:pwd  
:redir END
```

The contents of `@a` consist of three blank lines and then the normal expected output.

I tried to post process with something like this:

```
:let @b = substitute(@a, '\s*\(.\{-}\)\s*', '\1', '')
```

But the result is that `@b` has the same contents as `@a`.

Does anyone know a more effective (i.e. working) way to postprocess, or a replacement for `:redir` that doesn't have those extra lines?

Comment: Have you tried with `:let @b = substitute(@a, '\n', '', 'g')` ?

Comment: I just tried. That worked incredibly well! Now I feel stupid. =P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value in the *b* register is unchanged from the value in the *a* register because your regexp is failing to match.

1. You need to write grouping parentheses and the opening repetition brace with with backslashes.
   See [`:help /magic`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2fmagic); effectively, the [*magic*](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27magic%27) option is always on for [`substitute()`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#substitute%28%29) regexps.
2. [`\s` only matches SP and TAB](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cs) (not LF); but [`\_s` does include LF](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C_s) (alternately, you could use `\n` to just match LF).
3. You need to anchor the end of the expression so that the `\{-}` does not “give up” without matching anything (everything but the initial newlines unmatched, and thus unreplaced from the input string).

Here is a modified version of your substitution:

```
:let @b = substitute(@a,'\_s*\(.\{-}\)\_s*$','\1','')
```

---

It may be simpler to just think about deleting leading and trailing whitespace instead of matching everything in between. This can be done in a single substitution by using the `g` substitution modifier (repeated substitutions) with a regexp that uses the [alternation operator](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2Fbar) where one alternate is anchored to the start of the string (`%^`) and the other is anchored to the end of the string (`%$`).

```
substitute(@a,'\v%^\_s+|\_s+%$','','g')
```

This regexp uses [`\v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv) to avoid having to add backslashes for `%^`, `+`, `|`, and `%$`.

Change both occurrences of `\_s` to `\n` if you just want to trim leading/trailing newlines (instead of SP, TAB, or NL).

Comment: According to the doc, `substitute()` always acts as if 'magic' was set.