# Internal vim command output to external application

Tags: vim, pipe, clipboard

Say that I run `:set all` inside `vim` in command mode, this command outputs a lot of stuff as expected, how i can redirect this output to an external application capable of reading an incoming buffer, let's say `gedit` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [ViM: How to redirect ex command output into current buffer or file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/vim-how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file), you could redirect the output directly to a file, and then open it with Gedit or any other editor of choice just like any other file.

```
:redir >your_file | silent set all | redir END
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned by [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748475/internal-vim-command-output-to-external-application/16748534?noredirect=1#comment24124917_16748534), you could also copy this directly to your system clipboard if Vim is compiled with `+clipboard`. Then you could just paste it in another program use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> as usual.

```
:redir @+ | silent set all | redir END
```

Comment: so nothing "on the fly" and more direct like a pipe in the shell, like so `date | gedit` ?

Comment: @user2384250 It might be possible using something like `vim -c`, but I haven't seen anything like that before.

Comment: Today is `:redir` day! If Vim is compiled with clipboard support, the following may be more direct : `:redir @+ | silent set all | redir END`.