# Is there a way to search inside the digraphs in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to search inside the `:digraph` table in VIM ? the `\`is not working and my eyes are getting apart searching the glyphs I desire..

Answer (score 13):

try `:h digraph-table` there you can do search with `/ or ?`

Comment: Yes I know, but it does not covers all glyphs

Comment: Actually, it should cover all glyphs. Which ones are missing?

Comment: Yes you're right. I was stopping reading before the multibyte `:h digraph-table-mbyte`.

Comment: @user1435633 my understanding of your requirement is to **search**, instead of **reading**. if you are looking for some char, do a `/` and paste the char after the `/` to find it in that help doc.

Comment: My answer was not clear. I find out now the help page relative to the digraph table in which you can actually do a search with `/` . Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 7):

You can capture the actual `:digraph` output in a scratch buffer via:

```
:redir @a | silent digraph | redir END | new +setl\ buftype=nofile\ bufhidden=wipe | put! a
```

Comment: Thanks Ingo, this is a really useful snippet !

Answer (score 3):

Besides the answers given, you can try my [unicode-plugin](https://github.com/chrisbra/unicode.vim)
You can then use the `:Digraphs foobar` to search for digraphs whose name match foobar

Answer (score 1):

Combining [Ingo’s accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26234078/123109), [Bill Odom’s answer on directing ex commands to a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2573758/123109), and [Capturing ex command output](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Capture_ex_command_output) from the Vim Tips Wiki produces the following snippet for your `.vimrc`.

```
function! TabDigraphs()
  redir => message
    silent digraphs
  redir END
  tabnew
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe
  silent put =message
  setlocal nomodified
endfunction
command! TabDigraphs call TabDigraphs()
```