# How copy cmd output message to a variable

Tags: vim

How to store the result of %s/My_search//gn into a variable in vim.?

I need to the first word from the result.

means if the result is 3 matches on 5 lines then, i want that word "3"

Comment: What did you try and what do you want to do with that information?

Comment: I want to find the total occurance of my search pattern. (only the exact count). and paste that output into vim

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573021/how-to-redirect-ex-command-output-into-current-buffer-or-file to redirect output to a variable or buffer